# Slice Start Time of Data Factory does not match the start Time

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am generating a Data factory pipeline. The start and end time are set as below:

```
"start": "2017-09-21T14:00:00z",
"end": "2099-12-31T05:00:00Z",
"isPaused": false
```

The Scheduler shown as below:

```
"scheduler":{
    "frequency": "Day",
     "interval": 1
}
```

The input and output dataset availability shown as below:

```
"availability":{
    "frequency": "Day",
    "interval": 1
}
```

However, when I check the pipeline diagram. The output dataset shows an error sign. The status is 'pending execution'. Strangely, the slice start time is 12/31/2099 12:00AM UTC and the Slice end time is 01/01/2100 12:00 AM UTC. 
As the frequency of scheduler is 'Day'. I reason that the slice start time should be  something around 2017-09-22. How come it shot up to 12/31/2099? Can anyone explain it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by changing the start time one day earlier because I run the pipeline on 2017-09-21 so the start time should be earlier than the time I run the load.

```
"start": "2017-09-20T14:00:00z",
"end": "2099-12-31T05:00:00Z",
"isPaused": false
```